# I have two large tables in Access 2007, however neither has a unique identifier common to the tables, is it possible to join them?

Tags: ms-access

Each table has a unique identifier, but they don't line up with each other.  In order to combine them I would need to use at least 3 fields.  One table is about 1bn records and the other is about half that.  The second table has data that I need in the first table.

So my question is, am I able to combine two tables using multiple fields to look-up information in the second table?

Comment: How can you have a billion records in Access?

Answer (score 0):

As Remou stated:

> It is nearly always possible to
>   [match] up multiple fields.

To get around the Access's limitations on the number of records, can you **restrict the number of records returned in the query using a WHERE clause**? Surely you would not really want a billion records returned at any given moment?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can inner join on multiple columns.  With a billion records, though, in Access, the query might not succeed. You could export to CSV and import into SQLite, as an alternative.  Typically, the columns involved in the join would be indexed, either individually, or as a composite index, i.e. a single index using multiple columns.

Comment: If the original poster installed SQL Server Express it would just be a matter of linking some tables and doing an append query to get the data into SQL Server. Much easier than a CSV file.   Also on a stand online non networked system Jet is faster than SQL Server.  Although Access wouldn't be able to handle a billion records.

Comment: If it's SQL Server Express, you want to make sure it's 2008 R2, since that ups the file size limitation from 4GBs to 10GBs.

Comment: @Tony Toews: You want the OP to install SQL Server Express just so he can import data into SQL server?  You consider that "easier than a CSV file?" I just have to say that ease is in the eye of the beholder, and there are tradeoffs both ways. Also, Access is not faster than SQL Server. I've been using Access since version 2.0 (circa 1995) and SQLServer for 10 years. SQLServer on a properly configured server simply eats Access's lunch performance-wise on large datasets.  And "large" for Access is much fewer than a billion records. Ever get the "query too complex" error?